# Detect input changes and simultaneously written other input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two input text box. I want to if first input change and same time written other input.

I use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/LGAWY/) code. I try that but is not working when first page open. İf page refresh one time, this code working. And I write something with some options.
My codes is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aWGq5/4/)

```
$.event.special.inputchange = {
    setup: function() {
        var self = this, val;
        $.data(this, 'timer', window.setInterval(function() {
            val = self.value;
            if ( $.data( self, 'cache') != val ) {
                $.data( self, 'cache', val );
                $( self ).trigger( 'inputchange' );
            }
        }, 20));
    },
    teardown: function() {
        window.clearInterval( $.data(this, 'timer') );
    },
    add: function() {
        $.data(this, 'cache', this.value);
    }
};

$('input').on('inputchange', function() {
    var container = $("div.class1").first();
     $('#firstname').on('inputchange', function() {
        container.find("input.firstname").val(this.value);
    });
});
```

Steps :

1. Are there any changes,
2. Find first child in one class
3. First class value is equal changes

What can I do that?

Comment: you can use the on `input` listener

Comment: Working here http://jsfiddle.net/aWGq5/7/

Comment: @ShaunakD your changes is working. But can we use something instead of `container.find("input#firstname0").val(this.value);` Because input#firstname0 is manuel. can we mafe witf first child ?

Comment: Added it to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aWGq5/8/)**

For first child use `input:first`.  - **[`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)**

Try this snippet,

```
$('input#firstname').on('inputchange', function() {
    var container = $("div.class1").first();

    container.find("input:first").val(this.value);

});
```